# CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()) stop launching after subsequent exceptions

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

After launching several functions in a `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())` that throws exceptions :

The sentence `CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()).launch {Log.v("John","Doe")}` won't execute.

For example :

```
fun everySecond(){
    CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()).launch {
        Log.v("John", "Doe") //After 5 exceptions this part is not reached
        try{
            aFunctionThatMayThrowToSignalNetworkErrors() //I use exceptions as logic back-off
        } catch(e:Exception){
            Log.e("John", "Doe ERROR")
        }
    }
}
```

The function everySecond() is called from a `Service()`

`everySecond()` is launched every seconds and the catch blocks are executed well. After 5 exceptions throwed precisely, the part `Log.v("John", "Doe")` is not reached.

I use last `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3`

Comment: Can you clarify that your `everySecond` is launched more than 5 times and that your catch blocks are executed as well?

Comment: I was creating new `CoroutineScope()` everytime to be sure the exception throwed was not cancelling the Scope() as it shouldn't with `SupervisorJob()` but it was still not working. Sorry for not having clear explanations : it's a network function that throw if not connect/send, but after 5 times the Coroutine just don't run.

Comment: Is it a blocking function? Maybe you have somehow used up all of Dispatcher.Default’s threads.

Comment: Please verify if you at all invoke `everySecond()`. Also, maybe this is some kind of log deduplication? It doesn't seem related to the exception.

Comment: Oh, good catch. I think LogCat stops logging more than five identical logs in a row from the same package. Try tacking on `+ Random.nextInt()` to your log message.

Comment: Logcat don't stops logging for identical logs for API > 28.

Answer (score 0):

After @Tenfour04 suggestion, I tried to cancel the blocking call when reaching the exception and it has work.

My solution :

Use `private var socketScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()) //dont use only CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) because when to much exception it cancel further jobs`

```
fun everySecond(){
    socketScope.launch {
        Log.v("John", "Doe") //Now it can do infinite exceptions :)
        try{
            aFunctionThatMayThrowToSignalNetworkErrors() //I use exceptions as logic back-off
        } catch(e:IOException){
            Log.e("John", "Doe ERROR")
            //save data
            cancel()
        } catch(e:UninitializedPropertyAccessException){
            Log.e("John", "Doe ERROR")
            //save data
            cancel()
        } catch(e:NegativeArraySizeException){
            Log.e("John", "Doe ERROR")
            //save data
            cancel()
        } catch(e:Exception){
            Log.e("John", "Doe ERROR")
            //save data
            cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Yes **it was exhausting all the available thread of Dispatchers.IO**. Cancelling them made the tricks.